# Generic in base class: Is my Stacktrace missing a line?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, stack-trace

The Stacktrace of an exception i'm getting is:

```
/* snip */
at SomeSystemMethod()
at Namespace.Adapters.ListAdapterBase`1.GetObjects(String where)
at Namespace.Processes.MyProcess.Run()
/* snip */
```

This it seems that this is missing something after the second line, because ListAdapterBase is abstract and the method GetObjects is not called directly, but by another method of the child class:

```
public class ActualStateList : ListAdapterBase<ActualState>
{
    /* snip */
    public List<ActualState> GetByUserId(int userId)
    {
        return GetObjects(string.Format(
            WHERECLAUSE_BYUSERID, userId));
    }
    /* snip */
}
```

So my first question is, how can it be, that there is no call of `ActualStateList.GetByUserId()` or another child class or method in the Stacktrace?

And secondly: the `Run()` method uses 4 child classes of ListAdapterBase, can I somehow find out, in which one the exception happened? Does the number behind ListAdapterBase somehow lead to precisely one of the child classes?

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of the `Run` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question: Most likely `GetByUserId` is inlined in your Release build, that's why it isn't missing from the stack trace. Using the Debug build should show that method.

Second question: From the StackTrace you are getting, you can't infer which child class has been used. The number (`` `1 ``)  is part of the class name of `ListAdapterBase` and simply states that this class has one generic argument.

One thought however: As the JIT is able to inline `GetByUserId` you know certain things:

- The JIT knows at compile time which child class is used as `virtual` methods aren't inlined.
- Only child classes that call `GetObjects` are candidates for the specific child class used
- Only child classes where `GetObjects` is called in a [simple method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidnotario/archive/2004/11/01/250398.aspx) are candidates.

These points might help you find the specific child class.

Adding a pdb file could help even more as it would show the line number in the `Run` method that threw the exception. Adding pdb files is possible for Release builds, too.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit further? What is inlining? When does it happen? If some of the methods have more than just one line, does it mean, it can't be them, because they wouldn't been inlined? If I look with a tool like ILSpy or dotPeek on my Release Assembly will I see the inlining?

Comment: @Hinek: Inlining is explained in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion). The first sentence sums it up pretty good: "In computing, inline expansion, or inlining, is a manual or compiler optimization that replaces a function call site with the body of the callee"

Comment: @Hinek: You won't see the inlining in dotPeek as it only happens at runtime by the JIT compiler, not the C# compiler. (I fixed my answer accordingly).

Comment: @Hinek: What methods exactly are being inlined is not defined exactly, but [this blog post](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/aggressive-inlining-clr-45-jit) states some points. "More than one line" is not one of the criterias :-)

Comment: Thanks, that gives me some hints to search on.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said, the `GetByUserId` method seems to have been inlined by the compiler, which is why you don't see it in the stack trace.

The `` `1 `` after `ListAdapterBase` means that it's a generic type with one type argument, which of course does not help here because all your derived classes have one type argument. You won't be able to find which one it is from just a stack trace.